# Cannot assign domain to azure website because of previous usage

Tags: azure, dns

I can't point a domain name at a new azure website because it is apparently already pointed to a different azure website (which I don't own). I am the legitimate owner of the domain name and I can fulfil the criteria for linking the domain to a new site (i.e. set up CNAME, awverify etc) but within Azure it won't accept the linkage because it has been pointed at a different site in the past.

Is the legitimate owner of a domain locked out of using it in azure because a previous owner of the domain has used it in azure before allowing the domain registration to expire? Or is there some way around this problem?

(Microsoft support has been unable to give me any helpful advice thus far, I'm hoping that someone here might have overcome this problem)

Comment: I don't think it should create any issue. As you will add awverify.yournew.azurewebsites.net in CNAME of your domain. with in 4 hours you can add your domain url in Azurewebsites configuration. Please check are you able to pass this step. Because I have cleared this case once.

Comment: After the clearance of this step we can point domain to Azure website IP

Comment: That step didn't work for me - even a day after setting up awverify as CNAME and setting up the A record to point to the IP address, Azure will still not allow you to apply the domain name if it is currently pointed to some other website somewhere else on Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an actual limitation within Azure at the moment. I've raised a suggestion on the azure feedback mechanism here http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/9292002-stop-locking-domain-names-to-azure-websites-allow and a Microsoft support person has agreed that it is a problem scenario, and one that they will need to look into.

So unless anyone else knows better, I think this question can unfortunately be considered closed.

Comment: Happily Microsoft did eventually resolve this, so using the feedback mechanism appears to have worked. As such, I'm marking this as the answer.